# Vue.js - v-for to print object name only

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-for

I have a nested object and only wanted to print the object name. How do I do this in vue.js?

```
var object1 = {
  'obj1' : {
    'obj1a' : 'a',
    'obj1b' : 'b'
  },
  'obj2' : {
    'obj2c' : 'c',
    'obj2d' : 'd'
  }
}
```

This code prints the entire content of the object being iterated:

```
<div v-for="obj in object1" v-bind:key="obj">
  {{ obj }}
</div>
```

How can I make it only print strings `obj1` and `obj2`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `key,index` in [`v-for`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-for) loop like `v-for="(obj,key,index) in object1"`

```
<div v-for="(obj,key,index) in object1" v-bind:key="obj">
  {{ key }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use  `v-for="(value, key )` v-for as below

```
<div v-for="(value, key ) in object1" >
  {{ key }}
</div>
```